# Clickable image link sends people to wrong URL

Tags: php, images, customization, css, headers

On my website www.wilsonstransportation.com, on the header of our custome theme page, we have a "Get a Quote" image on the right hand side. When you click it, it is taking people to http://wilsonstransportation.com/wp-content/themes/wilsons/contact-us/get-a-quote . It should be sending people to www.wilsonstransportation.com/contact-us/get-a-quote . We are losing quite a bit of business because of this. In the header.php, this is what shows up:

```
<div class="subnavLinks">
<a href="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/contact-us/get-a-quote" class=""><img src="/uploads/quote.png"  class=""></a>
```

how do I change the URL to go to the normal page again? This all of a sudden changed when we updated a few wordpress things. HELP

Answer (score 2):

`bloginfo('template_url')` is the wrong function, you need `home_url`:

```
<div class="subnavLinks">
<a href="<?php echo home_url('/contact-us/get-a-quote'); ?>" class=""><img src="/uploads/quote.png"  class=""></a>
```

Comment: you sir, are a god!

Comment: @user34597 Not quite, but if you are satisfied with my answer, please click the tick next to it so that other disciples may see its glory.